# Customized DisplayAttribute:Name used in server side validation message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `IDisplayMetadataProvider` to provide translation for form elements in following way:

```
public class DisplayAttributeMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        var metadata = context.DisplayMetadata;

        var display = context.Attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        /* lines deleted to increase reability */

        metadata.DisplayName = () => new MakeItTranslatable(display.Name);
    }
}
```

With given model:

```
public class Model
{
    [Display(Name = "Account name")]
    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login)` gives proper result. Phrase "Account name" is translated.

However `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)` doesn't give proper validation message. Phrase "Account name" is not translated in validation message.

I am using server side validation (without jquery.validate.js), however attributes for client side are rendered properly. (Account Name = Nazwa konta)

[image: different validation]

What am I missing?

Comment: you mean you can't not see validation message or validation not fires on submit?

Comment: Perhaps you need to implement `IValidationMetadataProvider` as well?

Comment: What is the value of the `data-val-required` attribute in your input?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers validation is fired, I can see validation message, but field name is not tranlated

Comment: @StephenMuecke `data-val-required` has a proper validation message, I didn't notice it before, however in this case I am using server side validation (after submit). I am wondering now why mvc uses two different ways to achieve same result (error message for requiered attribute).

Comment: The `data-val-*` attributes are used for client side validation (for adding the rules to `jquery.validate.js`). But if you getting the correctly translated message in the `data-val-required` attribute, you should also be getting it it the server side validation (both internally call the `FormatErrorMessage()` method of `ValidationAttribute`)

Comment: @haim770 i did not implement `IValidationMetadataProvider` should I? Attributes for client side validation are rendered properly.